# How to get just FileName Parse.com database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am in little bit problem, I get the filename from Parse.com database like this.

```
  object.get("thumbnailImage").name();
```

and it returns me like this name.

```
tfss-63deff46-ab55-4230-b71c-1d77d54f9bfa-Pendulum.png
```

But i want to get exact filename for example

```
Pendulum.png
```

How can I get it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var name = object.get("thumbnailImage").name();
var nameParts = name.split("-");
var filename = nameParts[nameParts.length - 1];
```

That should work

```
var filename = object.get("thumbnailImage").name().split("-").pop();
```

That might also work

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the accepted answer is that any filename that contains "-" gets chopped.

I agree it's the most viable workaround at the moment, but it would be nice if Parse could provide the "displayName" as a separate property.